# Database design for availability (time intervals) table

Tags: mysql

In my web-app I have Parents and Babysitters.
Babysitters will declare an availability to work (time intervals) which will be stored in Availability Table.
Parents will express their needs also in time intervals (no need to be stored at the moment).
So I designed my availability table like this:

```
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| week_day   | tinyint(1)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| hour_start | varchar(10)         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| hour_end   | varchar(10)         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

and data examples are

```
+---------+----------+------------+------------+
| user_id | week_day | hour_start | hour_end   |
+---------+----------+------------+------------+
|      10 |        0 | 08:00 a.m. | 10:00 a.m  |
|      10 |        0 | 02:00 p.m. | 04:00 p.m. |
|      10 |        1 | 10:00 p.m. | 11:00 p.m. |
|      10 |        2 | 09:00 a.m. | 12:00 a.m. |
|      10 |        3 | 03:00 p.m. | 05:00 p.m. |
|      10 |        4 | 10:00 a.m. | 12:00 a.m. |
|      10 |        5 | 12:30 a.m. | 02:00 p.m. |
|      10 |        6 | 12:30 a.m. | 02:00 p.m. |
+---------+----------+------------+------------+
```

As you can see for week_day = 0 (monday) the babysitter is available for two time slots.
My questions are:
1) is there a better way to store this informations?
2) is var_char(10) for hour_start and hour_end columns a proper format?
3) is there some benefit if I add an ID primary column (which I don't think I will ever query)?
4) is it better if I store all the data for columns **week_day**, **hour_start**, **hour_end** in a serialised array?

Comment: hour_start and hour_end should be timestamp datatype or float number so it's easier to query. hour_start and hour_end could also be integers in seconds or minutes from midnight. and by convention monday is day 1, sunday could be day 0 or day 7.

Comment: Yes. No. no. no.

Comment: MUL? Eh????????

Answer (score 1):

Your questions:

1. is there a better way to store this informations?
2. is var_char(10) for hour_start and hour_end columns a proper format?
3. is there some benefit if I add an ID primary column (which I don't think I will ever query)?
4. is it better if I store all the data for columns week_day, hour_start, hour_end in a serialised array?

Answers:

1. Yes. Hour Start and Hour End should be could as TIMESTAMP. You just ignore the date part by picking a date and using that for each. They could also be stored as INT in minutes. 1am would be 60, 2am as 120, etc.
2. No. If you need to compare to a date time, it could become complicated. It could work if the times are stored in 24 hour format (no am/pm), but then you are doing string compares against some date time.
3. Absolutely! If you need to build an editor, it allows you to specify which row you are editing, and which to update when it's saved.
4. No idea. That really depends on how they are used in your application. If you need to build SQL queries that involve the values (ie. list all babysitters available between two date times), it would not be a good idea.